# Calculate percentage of total returns 0

Tags: sql-server, select, percentage

I wish to return a percentage grouped by each `id_cerinta`, like how many of the `subcerinteProiect` recordings are having `acoperire= 'acoperita'` divided to all the `subcerinteProiect` recordings according to the `id_sarcina` they are grouped by

[image]

I tried something like :

```
SELECT 
    id_cerinta,
    SUM(CASE WHEN acoperire = 'acoperita' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
        / COUNT(*) * 100 AS nr_subcerinte_acoperit 
FROM 
    subcerinteProiect 
GROUP BY 
    id_cerinta
```

But it doesn't work too good. It returns only 0..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is due to integer math. Try these:

```
SELECT 5/100, 57/100, 99/100;
```

Results are all 0.

Now try:

```
SELECT 5.0/100, 57.0/100, 99.0/100;
```

Better results, right?

So for your query:

```
SELECT 
    id_cerinta, 
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(5,2), 
        SUM(CASE WHEN acoperire = 'acoperita' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
            / COUNT(*) * 100.0) AS nr_subcerinte_acoperit 
FROM 
    subcerinteProiect 
GROUP BY
    id_cerinta
```

Comment: I thought so too, but the results are now, 0.00 ....all...I don't know where is the issue...I have recordings with acoperire ='acoperita....

Comment: @TBogdan did you *COPY* my query, or did you edit your existing query with changes you may or may not have noticed? Did you change the third line to have `100.0` instead of `100`?

Comment: DONE, CONVERT(DECIMAL(5,2) should olso be used on COUNT (*) , THANKS MAN

Comment: do you know how can I also return in this query, another field from another table that is here foreign key? i'm refering to id_cerinta, and I would like to return from another table cerinte the field name value from cerinte

Comment: @TBogdan no, convert DECIMAL(5,2) should not be used on COUNT(*). What happens when you have more than 999 rows in your table? The * 100.0 should work. If not, please post a repro. And as for your other question, please don't change the scope of your question in a comment. Start a new question, showing sample data and desired results.